# Link Not Changing Color On Phone

Tags: css

I made all my links like this

```
a:link {
color:#3C6;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited {
color:#3C6;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
color:#3C6;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:active {
color:#3C6;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

But I one link white so I made it like this.

```
Contact Us 
<a title="phone" class="topphone" style="color:#FFF;"><?php echo $phone ?></a></div>
```

And also added CSS

```
.topphone {
color:#FFF;
}
```

But still nothing on my phone. Still green, what do I do??

Comment: may be cache problem. clear cache.

Comment: FWIW your PHP code is irrelevant. Also, `a { text-decoration:none }` will cover all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Plz give a shot to the following..

```
a.topphone {
color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove inline style from your code and then use below CSS.

```
a.topphone {
color:#FFF !important;
}
```

CSS Inline style is removed in below line.

```
<a title="phone" class="topphone"><?php echo $phone ?></a></div>
```

**One Suggestion:** you should optimized your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove inline-CSS

**or**

add !important for the color values in css

```
a.topphone {
color:#FFF !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline css and add this code

```
a.topphone { color:#fff;}

a.topphone:hover { color:#3C6; text-decoration:none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nponnen/VbnLm/